# MPDF how to use alpha transparent?

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

im using MPDF to create a pdf file with full page background. I want to make a layout on it like this image.
[image]

I think need to use alpha transparent, but i dont know how

This is my code

```
<?php
$pdfOptions = array(
    'mode'              => 'utf-8',
    'format'                => 'A4-L',
    'img_dpi'               => 300,
    'dpi'                   => 300,
);
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($pdfOptions);

//==============================================================

$html='
<style>
#cover {
  background-color: #dddddd;

}
</style>

<div id="cover" style="position: absolute; left:0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 297mm; height: 50mm;">
</div>
';

$mpdf->WriteHTML("<html><body style='background-image:url(\"images/1.jpg\"); background-image-resize: 5; background-position: top center;'></body></html>");

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Text for item 1</p>');

$mpdf->Output(); 
exit;

?>
```

[image]

Im trying to use opacity

```
#cover {
width: 297mm;
 height: 50mm;
  background-image: url("images/b.png");
  background-image-resize: 5;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image-opacity: 0.5;

}
```

but the result like this
[image]

Comment: What about the `opacity` style attribute, or using #DDDDDD20 for the `background-color` - where 20 is the opacity (32/255 = 12.5%)

Comment: #DDDDDD20 not work, opacity only supported on background-image. i update my post about opacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rgba is [supported by mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html), so the style should be something like this, where last is alpha value:

```
<style>
#cover {
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.5);
}
</style>
```